# RestBed clone failed from github

Tags: github, restbed

While cloning the restbed repo, we are getting below error and is taking a lot of time.

```
$ git submodule update --init --recursive
Submodule 'dependency/asio' (https://github.com/corvusoft/asio-dependency) registered for path 'dependency/asio'
Submodule 'dependency/catch' (https://github.com/corvusoft/catch-dependency) registered for path 'dependency/catch'
Submodule 'dependency/openssl' (https://github.com/corvusoft/openssl-dependency) registered for path 'dependency/openssl'
Cloning into '${HOME}/restbed/dependency/asio'...

error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSL read: errno -5961
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/corvusoft/asio-dependency' into submodule path '${HOME}/restbed/dependency/asio' failed
Failed to clone 'dependency/asio'. Retry scheduled
```

Is there something wrong with the repo?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What occurs when you run `git clone --recursive https://github.com/corvusoft/restbed.git`

Comment: There were no differences when using "submodule" option or "recursive clone" option. Looks like the dependency lib on "asio" was causing the timeout. Now, we found that both "--recursive" and 'submodule" are working fine. Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: Very odd.  Not seent hat behavior from GitHub before.  Glad to hear it has started working again :D